# sort data in ListView alphabetical order

Tags: android, listview, alphabetical-sort

I need help on how I list my data in the ListView alphabetical. If I add more data to foldeData it would be nice if I didn't have to manually move the existing data in order to list them alphabetical.

I have copied part of the code from MainActivity:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView minPastaTimer, maxPastaTimer, tv_start, tv_stop, choice; 

    int minTid, maxTid;

    private ListView listViewArticles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Folder[] folderData = new Folder[4];    



       folderData[0] = new Folder(R.drawable.icon_music_folder, "Acomo Pepe", (getString(R.string.acomo_pepe)), "Kogetid 9-10min");
       folderData[1] = new Folder(R.drawable.icon_music_folder, "Bucatini", (getString(R.string.Bucatini)),"Kogetid 9-10min");
       folderData[2] = new Folder(R.drawable.icon_music_folder, "Bumbola", (getString(R.string.Bumbola)),"Kogetid 9-10min");
       folderData[3] = new Folder(R.drawable.icon_music_folder, "Cannelloni", (getString(R.string.Cannelloni)),"Kogetid 9-10min");





       FolderAdapter adapter = new FolderAdapter(this,
               R.layout.listview_item_row, folderData);



       listViewArticles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       listViewArticles.setAdapter(adapter);

    minPastaTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minPastaTimer);
    minPastaTimer.setText("00:00:00");
    maxPastaTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxPastaTimer);
    choice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_choice);
    maxPastaTimer.setText("00:00:00");
    Button btn_italy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_italy);
    Button btn_danish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_danish);

    tv_start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_start);
    tv_start.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_stop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_stop);
    tv_stop.setOnClickListener(this);


    listViewArticles.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

           String listItemText = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewFolderName))
                    .getText()
                    .toString();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "You clicked: " + listItemText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();       

           if (listItemText.equals("Acomo Pepe")){
              minTid=10000;
              maxTid=20000;
              choice.setText("Acomo Pepe: " + (getString(R.string.acomo_pepe)));
              minPastaTimer.setText("00:08:00");
              maxPastaTimer.setText("00:09:00");
           }
           else if (listItemText.equals("Bucatini")){
            minTid=540000;
            maxTid=600000;
            choice.setText("Bucatini - Kogetid: " + (minTid/60/1000) + ("-") +(maxTid/60/1000) + ("min"));
            minPastaTimer.setText("00:09:00");
            maxPastaTimer.setText("00:10:00");
           }   
           else if (listItemText.equals("Bumbola")){
                minTid=15000;
                maxTid=30000;
                minPastaTimer.setText("00:10:00");
                maxPastaTimer.setText("00:11:00");
              }
           else if (listItemText.equals("Cannelloni")){
                minTid=15000;
            maxTid=30000;
            minPastaTimer.setText("00:11:00");
            maxPastaTimer.setText("00:12:00");
            }  


        }
    });
```

FolderAdapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Folder> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Folder data[] = null;


     // @mContext - app context

     // @layoutResourceId - the listview_item_row.xml

     // @data - the ListItem data

    public FolderAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, Folder[] data) {

        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }


     // @We'll overried the getView method which is called for every ListItem we have.

     // @There are lots of different caching techniques for Android ListView to
     // achieve better performace especially if you are going to have a very long ListView.

     // @convertView - the cache of list item row layout, if it is null, inflate new

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            // inflate the listview_item_row.xml parent
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        // get the elements in the layout
        ImageView imageViewFolderIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFolderIcon);
        TextView textViewFolderName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFolderName);
        TextView textViewFolderDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFolderDescription);
        TextView textViewFolderBoilTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFolderBoilTime);


        // Set the data for the list item. You can also set tags here if you want.

        Folder folder = data[position];

        imageViewFolderIcon.setImageResource(folder.folderIcon);
        textViewFolderName.setText(folder.folderName);
        textViewFolderDescription.setText(folder.folderDescription);
        textViewFolderBoilTime.setText(folder.folderBoilTime);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice would be sorting the list before the calling adaptor.notifyDataChanged() method. Good thing is you do not have to do it manually, just use comparator for sorting.

You can see a comparator [example in this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm)

Comment: His "Folder" type must be comparable, or create a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array as datasource for the list, first use a List. At least, this class extends Collection.

You can define a comparator (e.g define compareTo() on your custom type) and sort your collection before you show it:

```
Collections.sort(<your_list>);
```

EDIT: For general collection ordering, see [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)